# Убрать лишнюю строку заголовка и оставить значения NULL в первой строке

Tags: sql

Есть задача собрать заголовок из 2 строк, причем в первой строке должны быть NULL, а также вывести данные из таблицы.

примерно так:

```
null                    dateBegin      dateEnd           null
Наименование            Дата начала    Дата окончания    Цена
Конфета 1               2020-01-01     2020-01-01        50
Конфета 2               2020-01-02     2020-03-02        150
```

Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (
 name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
,beginDt DATE
,endDt DATE
,price DECIMAL(9,2));

INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES
('конфета 1','2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', 50)
,('конфета 2','2020-01-02', '2020-03-02', 150);

SELECT
  'NULL' AS  'Наименование'
 ,'dateBegin' AS 'Дата начала'
 ,'dateEnd' AS 'Дата окончания'
 ,'NULL' AS 'Цена'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Наименование'
 ,'Дата начала'
 ,'Дата окончания'
 ,'Цена'
 UNION ALL
SELECT
  name AS 'Наименование'
 ,CAST(beginDt AS VARCHAR(15)) AS 'Дата начала'
 ,CAST(endDt AS VARCHAR(15)) AS 'Дата окончания'
 ,CAST(price AS VARCHAR(15)) AS 'Цена'
FROM #tbl
```

Есть первая лишняя строка, ее б убрать как-то

```
Наименование    Дата начала Дата окончания  Цена
NULL            dateBegin   dateEnd         NULL
Наименование    Дата начала Дата окончания  Цена
конфета 1       2020-01-01  2020-02-01      50
конфета 2       2020-01-02  2020-03-02      150
```

Просто нельзя сделать запрос типа

```
SELECT
     'Наименование' AS NULL
     ,'Дата начала' AS dateBegin
     ,'Дата окончания' AS dateEnd
     ,'Цена' AS NULL
```

ибо **Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "NULL".**

Comment: Что за лишняя строка? Задача странная, но по коду у вас должно вывестись 4 строки. Может у таблица не пустая?

Comment: ```Наименование Дата начала Дата окончания Цена
NULL                 dateBegin dateEnd                 NULL
Наименование Дата начала Дата окончания Цена
конфета 1        2020-01-01 2020-02-01        50.50
конфета 2        2020-01-02 2020-02-02        55.50

Comment: В запросе у вас 1+1+2 записей. SQL корректный. Какая БД, IDE?

Comment: `SELECT 'Наименование' AS 'NULL' …`

Answer (score 1):

Создание, вставка и сам запрос написаны корректно. Данных возвращается 4 записи. Это можно проверить, сделав подзапрос `select count(*) from (<ваш юнион>)`.

То что вы называете лишней строкой, а думаю, это шапка у таблицы. В SQL мы можем управлять только названием колонок, управление видимостью шапки происходит на стороне клиента.

С точки зрения как SQL, так и привычного интерфейса решение очень спорное. Так как вы пытаетесь добавить интерфейсные части в данные.

Может быть будет достаточно указать название в следующем формате `Дата начала\dateBegin` или настраивать отображение на клиенте с помощью дополнительных компонентов.

Comment: Вы правы, логичнее это сделать в интерфейсе, но проблема в том что эта табличка попадает в эксельку, а далее эксельку будут в другой программе использовать.В идеале - дать готовый результат.

Comment: В эксель можно использовать шаблоны. Запускать макросы для объединения удаления строк, ячеек, данных  и т.д.